# When i deploy my solution the Login controller starts a looping

Tags: c#

When i compile the code in the localhost it starts normally but when i deploy in heroku or aws it starts doing a loop in the url: east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%
My Startup

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using BaseProject.DAO.AppDbContext;
using BaseProject.DAO.Interface.IRepository;
using BaseProject.DAO.Interface.IService;
using BaseProject.DAO.Models;
using BaseProject.DAO.Repository;
using BaseProject.DAO.Service;

namespace VascoVasconcellos.API
{
   public class Program
   {

      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

         var services = builder.Services;


         #region Service
         services.AddScoped<IServiceEtiqueta, ServiceEtiqueta>();
         services.AddScoped<IServiceLogAcesso, ServiceLogAcesso>();
         services.AddScoped<IServiceLogErro, ServiceLogErro>();
         services.AddScoped<IServiceLogOperacao, ServiceLogOperacao>();
         services.AddScoped<IServiceUsuario, ServiceUsuario>();
         services.AddScoped<IServiceVendas, ServiceVendas>();
         services.AddScoped<IServiceBoleta, ServiceBoleta>();
         services.AddScoped<IServiceClientes, ServiceClientes>();
         services.AddScoped<IServiceOrcamentos, ServiceOrcamentos>();
         services.AddScoped<IServiceProdutos, ServiceProdutos>();
         services.AddScoped<IServiceProdutosColunas, ServiceProdutosColunas>();
         #endregion

         #region Repository
         services.AddScoped<IRepositoryEtiqueta, RepositoryEtiqueta>();
         services.AddScoped<IRepositoryLogAcesso, RepositoryLogAcesso>();
         services.AddScoped<IRepositoryLogErro, RepositoryLogErro>();
         services.AddScoped<IRepositoryLogOperacao, RepositoryLogOperacao>();
         services.AddScoped<IRepositoryLogOperacao, RepositoryLogOperacao>();
         services.AddScoped<IRepositoryUsuario, RepositoryUsuario>();
         services.AddScoped<IRepositoryVendas, RepositoryVendas>();
         services.AddScoped<IRepositoryBoleta, RepositoryBoleta>();
         services.AddScoped<IRepositoryClientes, RepositoryClientes>();
         services.AddScoped<IRepositoryOrcamentos, RepositoryOrcamentos>();
         services.AddScoped<IRepositoryProdutos, RepositoryProdutos>();
         services.AddScoped<IRepositoryProdutosColunas, RepositoryProdutosColunas>();
         #endregion


         var config = builder.Configuration;
         var env = builder.Environment;

         var connectionString = config.GetConnectionString(env.EnvironmentName);

         services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o =>
            o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));

         services.AddDbContext<MySqlDbContext>(options =>
         {
            options.UseMySql(
               connectionString,
               ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)
               );
         });

         services.AddDefaultIdentity<AspNetUsers>(options =>
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false
         ).AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<MySqlDbContext>();

         services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
         {
            config.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
         });

         services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
      options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);


         services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
         services.AddRazorPages();
         services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
         );

         // Add services to the container.
         builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

         // Add services to the container.
         builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

         var app = builder.Build();

         // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
         if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
         {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Dashboard/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
         }

         app.UseHttpsRedirection();
         app.UseStaticFiles();

         app.UseRouting();

         app.UseAuthorization();

         app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Dashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

         app.MapRazorPages();

         app.Run();
      }
   }
}
```

Account Controller

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using VascoVasconcellos.DAO.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using BaseProject.DAO.Models.VM;
using BaseProject.DAO.Interface.IService;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace VascoVasconcellos.API.Controllers
{
   [Route("[controller]")]
   public class AccountController : Controller
   {
      private readonly ILogger<AccountController> _logger;
      private UserManager<AspNetUsers> _userManager;
      private RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
      private SignInManager<AspNetUsers> _signInManager;
      private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
      private readonly IServiceLogAcesso _serviceLogAcesso;
      private readonly IServiceUsuario _serviceUsuario;

      public AccountController(
         ILogger<AccountController> logger,
         UserManager<AspNetUsers> userManager,
         RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
         SignInManager<AspNetUsers> signInManager,
         IMemoryCache memoryCache,
         IServiceLogAcesso serviceLogAcesso,
         IServiceUsuario serviceUsuario
         )
      {
         _logger = logger;
         _userManager = userManager;
         _roleManager = roleManager;
         _signInManager = signInManager;
         _memoryCache = memoryCache;
         _serviceLogAcesso = serviceLogAcesso;
         _serviceUsuario = serviceUsuario;
      }

      [HttpGet("Login")]
      public IActionResult Login()
      {
         if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
         {
            return View();
         }
         else
         {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
         }
      }

      [HttpPost("Login")]
      public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LogInVM model)
      {
         if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Json(new { Ok = false, Title = "Erro", Message = "Dados inválidos!" });

         var user = _userManager.ObterPorUserName(model.Nome);

         if (user == null)
         {
            return Json(new
            {
               Ok = false,
               Title = "Erro",
               Message = "Nome ou senha incorreto!",
            });
         }

         if (await _userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user))
         {
            var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
            var end = user.LockoutEnd.Value;
            var minutes = Math.Ceiling((end - now).TotalMinutes);
            return Json(new
            {
               Ok = false,
               Title = "Erro",
               Message = $"Devido a várias tentativas de acesso, a sua conta foi bloqueada. Tente novamente em {minutes + (minutes == 1 ? " minuto" : " minutos")}!",
            });
         }

         var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, true, true);

         var usuario = _serviceUsuario.ObterPorIdAspNet(user.Id);

         if (!result.Succeeded)
         {
            GerarLogAcesso(usuario.Id, false);

            return Json(new
            {
               Ok = false,
               Title = "Erro",
               Message = "Nome ou senha incorreto!",
            });
         }

         return Json(new
         {
            Ok = true,
            Title = "Sucesso",
            Message = "Sucesso na confirmação de login e senha!",
         });
      }

      [Authorize]
      [HttpGet("Logout")]
      public IActionResult Logout()
      {
         foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies)
         {
            if (cookie.Key == "acceptCookies") continue;
            Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key);
         }

         return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
      }

      public bool GerarLogAcesso(int id, bool status)
      {
         var LogAcesso = new LogAcesso
         {
            IdUsuario = id,
            Data = DateTime.Now,
            Status = "Login realizado",
         };
         return _serviceLogAcesso.Adicionar(LogAcesso);
      }
   }
}
```